# Django caching a large list

Tags: django, caching, memcached, deserialization, pickle

My django application deals with 25MB binary files.  Each of them has about 100,000 "records" of 256 bytes each.

It takes me about 7 seconds to read the binary file from disk and decode it using python's struct module.  I turn the data into a list of about 100,000 items, where each item is a dictionary with values of various types (float, string, etc.).

My django views need to search through this list.  Clearly 7 seconds is too long.

I've tried using django's low-level caching API to cache the whole list, but that won't work because there's a maximum size limit of 1MB for any single cached item.  I've tried caching the 100,000 list items individually, but that takes a lot more than 7 seconds - most of the time is spent unpickling the items.

Is there a convenient way to store a large list in memory between requests?  Can you think of another way to cache the object for use by my django app?

Comment: is using numpy.array possible?

Comment: Have you considered using a database?

Comment: James R: I can't see the connection between numpy.array and my caching problem.
Ignacio: Yes, that could work - I'd store each of the 100,000 items as a django model instance, and use the ORM to recall the data on subsequent requests...  But I was hoping to find a simpler memory-based solution.

Comment: numpy.array tends to be efficient when storing large arrays of numbers. If you aren't storing numbers, than it's not something that would be useful

Comment: Also, if it's flat, you should might consider using mongo or casandra.

Answer (score 9):

edit the item size limit to be 10m (larger than 1m), add

```
-I 10m
```

to /etc/memcached.conf and restart memcached

also edit this class in memcached.py located in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/cache/backends to look like this:

```
class MemcachedCache(BaseMemcachedCache):
"An implementation of a cache binding using python-memcached"
def __init__(self, server, params):
    import memcache
    memcache.SERVER_MAX_VALUE_LENGTH = 1024*1024*10 #added limit to accept 10mb
    super(MemcachedCache, self).__init__(server, params,
                                         library=memcache,
                                         value_not_found_exception=ValueError)
```

Comment: This is on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS of course... file locations may vary for your distro.

Comment: Just wasted several hours trying to work this out... couldn't figure out if memcache or Django was to blame, then realised it was both! Cheers

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490819/how-to-tell-django-that-memcached-running-with-item-size-larger-than-default

Comment: Actually, this did NOT work for me due to unexpected behaviour from python-memcache, which I've just reported. See https://github.com/linsomniac/python-memcached/issues/13

Comment: This doesn't work for me either. I fixed it using pylibmc, instead of python-memcache.

Comment: This is no longer necessary, and can be done from settings, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66762884/548736

Answer (score 4):

I'm not able to add comments yet, but I wanted to share my quick fix around this problem, since I had the same problem with python-memcached behaving strangely when you change the `SERVER_MAX_VALUE_LENGTH` at import time.

Well, besides the `__init__` edit that FizxMike suggests you can also edit the _cache property in the same class. Doing so you can instantiate the python-memcached Client passing the `server_max_value_length` explicitly, like this:

```
from django.core.cache.backends.memcached import BaseMemcachedCache

DEFAULT_MAX_VALUE_LENGTH = 1024 * 1024

class MemcachedCache(BaseMemcachedCache):
    def __init__(self, server, params):
        #options from the settings['CACHE'][connection]
        self._options = params.get("OPTIONS", {})
        import memcache
        memcache.SERVER_MAX_VALUE_LENGTH = self._options.get('SERVER_MAX_VALUE_LENGTH', DEFAULT_MAX_VALUE_LENGTH)

        super(MemcachedCache, self).__init__(server, params,
                                             library=memcache,
                                             value_not_found_exception=ValueError)

    @property
    def _cache(self):
        if getattr(self, '_client', None) is None:
            server_max_value_length = self._options.get("SERVER_MAX_VALUE_LENGTH", DEFAULT_MAX_VALUE_LENGTH)
            #one could optionally send more parameters here through the options settings,
            #I simplified here for brevity
            self._client = self._lib.Client(self._servers,
                server_max_value_length=server_max_value_length)

        return self._client
```

I also prefer to create another backend that inherits from BaseMemcachedCache and use it instead of editing django code.

here's the django memcached backend module for reference:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/cache/backends/memcached.py

Thanks for all the help on this thread!