# How to tell Django, that memcached running with item-size larger than default?

Tags: python, django, caching, memcached

Im using new setting to increase item size in memcached, but i cant store something larger than 1mb through Django backend. 
I know that `memcache` module require some setting to achieve thath, and Django use this module in backend.

Answer (score 7):

From [Maximum size of object that can be saved in memcached with memcache.py](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1440773/58107):

> There are two entries about that in the memcached FAQ :
>
> - What is the maximum data size you can store? Why are items limited to
>     1 megabyte in size? The answer to the first one is (quoting, emphasis
>     mine) :
> - The maximum size of a value you can store in memcached is 1 megabyte.
>     If your data is larger, consider clientside compression or splitting
>     the value up into multiple keys.
>
> So I'm guessing your 11MB file is quite too big to fit in one
>   memcached entry.

If you do really want to cache larger objects, you will have to subclass Django's MemcachedCache as it [doesn't allow you to pass in options](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/cache/backends/memcached.py#L163):

```
self._client = self._lib.Client(self._servers, pickleProtocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Example subclass implementation:

```
from django.core.cache.backends.memcached import MemcachedCache

class LargeMemcachedCache(MemcachedCache):
    "Memcached cache for large objects"

    @property
    def _cache(self):
        if getattr(self, '_client', None) is None:
            self._client = self._lib.Client(self._servers, 
                           pickleProtocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL, 
                           server_max_value_length = 1024*1024*10)
        return self._client
```

Answer (score 4):

In more recent Django versions you don't need to subclass the cache class, you can instead specify the arguments passed to the cache class's constructor in `OPTIONS`:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
        'KEY_FUNCTION': 'some.path.to.a.function',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'server_max_value_length': 1024 * 1024 * 10
        }
    }
}
```

See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#cache-arguments).

Note that you must also increase the size in memcached itself by adding the following line:

```
-I 10m
```

to `/etc/memcached.conf` and restarting it:

```
sudo service memcached restart
```

Answer (score 1):

Django deprecated the use of Memcached after 4.1

Instead of MemcachedCache you can use PyMemcacheCache
so BACKEND becomes

```
"BACKEND": "django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyMemcacheCache",
```

like before, the default object_size_limit of memcache is 1mb, but *'serve_max_value_length'* is no longer used.
Whatever size limit you set manually in the memcache config will be used by PyMemcacheCache
in my case, running on Debian, I had to add the following line to */etc/memcached.conf*

```
-I 10m
```

this made the size limit to 10 mb