# Django: Making sure a complex object is accessible throughout multiple view calls

Tags: django

for a project, I am trying to create a web-app that, among other things, allows training of machine learning agents using python libraries such as Dedupe or TensorFlow. In cases such as Dedupe, I need to provide an interface for active learning, which I currently realize through jquery based ajax calls to a view that takes and sends the necessary training data.

The problem is that I need this agent object to stay alive throughout multiple view calls and be accessible by each individual call. I have tried realizing this via the built-in cache system using Memcached, but the serialization does not seem to keep all the info intact, and while I am technically able to restore the object from the cache, this appears to break the training algorithm.

Essentially, I want to keep the object alive within the application itself (rather than an external memory store) and be able to access it from another view, but I am at a bit of a loss of how to realize this.

If someone knows the proper technique to achieve this, I would be very grateful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow up with this question, I have since realized that the behavior shown seemed to have been an effect of trying to use the result of a method call from the object loaded from cache directly in the return properties of a view. Specifically, my code looked as follows:

```py
#model is the object loaded from cache
#this returns the wrong object (same object as on an earlier call)
return JsonResponse({"pairs": model.uncertain_pairs()})
```

and was changed to the following

```py
#model is the object loaded from cache
#this returns the correct object (calls and returns the model.uncertain_pairs() method properly)
uncertain = model.uncertain_pairs()
return JsonResponse({"pairs": uncertain})
```

I am unsure if this specifically happens due to an implementation from Dedupe or Django side or due to Python, but this has undoubtedly fixed the issue.

To return back to the question, Django does seem to be able to properly (de-)serialize objects and their properties in cache, as long as the cache is set up properly (see [Apparent bug storing large keys in django memcached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143159/apparent-bug-storing-large-keys-in-django-memcached) which I also had to deal with)